# At least one project didn't migrate. How can I have sure all files was migrated?

Tags: azure-devops, opshub

Migration failures shows one messages: OH-SCM-009: Error occurred while sync. No matching items found in $/Sis/.../App_Start/BundleConfig.cs on the server, or you do not have permission to access them. It seems changeset has items across team projects and all such projects are not selected in configuration. Please create new configuration selecting all such projects to allow processing of this changeset.

The messages is about one file but actually all the project failed.
How to force to include the project in configuration?
How can I have sure all projects and files was migrated?

Answer (score 1):

When you start utility, after selecting Source and Target end point, select all projects that you want to migrate.

If you are migrating source control, then select dependent project as well.
(Dependent means, if you branch from one project to another or copied data from one project to another then select both)

As there can be indirect dependencies between file versions, changeset, labels etc. So changeset are processed in order. So the cause of failure needs to be rectified before continuing with the migration.